# How do I include images on my java applet on a website?

Tags: java, html, image, security, applet

I was able to embed my java applet onto a website using the following HTML code.

```html
<applet name = "Project" code = "Project.class" archive="Project.jar"    
codebase="https://project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" width=800 height = 800>
</applet>
```

I kept my code on the google code database and used the TortoiseSVN to place my jar file and other files  into that database including my image files.

However my image files didn't show up. I already signed my jar and all other class files, but I didn't sign my images. I didn't think I needed to. When I open the website, all other components of my program work, except for the images. None of the images show up.

In my appletviewer, the images do show up, and I am using the following code to get and show the image.

```
 class SwingPanel extends JPanel{
    Image bg;
    SwingPanel(){
        bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("spacebg.jpg");
    }
  }
 //In another class
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){//PaintComponent
            super.paintComponent(g);//Super
            g.drawImage(bg,0,0,800,800,this);
    }
```

I have another image as well which uses the similar structure as shown above.

How can I get the images to show up on the website?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: The original program was a JFrame, and I have a copy of that file. However, after self research I found that it would be easier to use the applet format because I can directly use the HTML code I referred to above and place it onto the website from there. I looked at the link and it seems interesting. Just FYI this is an extension from a class project, and in our class we learned about JApplets to get the basic foundation, and to be exposed to HTML. And then dove into JFrame after that. In my opinion, this method is much more effective, because one gets exposure, as well as alternate methods.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are inside your .jar file, you can access them using the `getResource` method of [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

```
bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
    SwingPanel.class.getResource("spacebg.jpg"));
```

The above code looks for spacebg.jpg in the same package that contains the SwingPanel class.

If you are deploying the image outside of your .jar file, and placing it in the same directory as the .jar file on the web server, you can create a URL relative to [the applet's location](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase--):

```
bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
    new URL(applet.getCodeBase(), "spacebg.jpg"));
```

Answer (score -2):

You must include full web address in a resource location string.

Instead of this:

```
bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("spacebg.jpg");
```

You must use:

```
bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("http://location-of-image/spacebg.jpg");
```

Or if it is in the jarfile:

You must use:

```
bg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("package-of-class/spacebg.jpg").getFile());
```

Comment: Your use of `getResource` is correct, but the [documentation for Toolkit.getImage(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage-java.lang.String-) clearly states that the String argument is a file name, not a URL.  Your example will not work.

Comment: please remove the -1, you may use URL.getFile()

Comment: URL.getFile() does *not* return a file name.  It returns the path portion of a URL, which might contain escaped octets and therefore is not guaranteed to correspond to an existing file path.  The method is named getFile() because the URL class is very old, part of Java 1.0 in fact, and back then, URLs frequently referred to physical files (such as in ftp: URLs).  Compare `new URL("file:/C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft")` with `new File("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft")`.

Comment: In this case where the applet is in jar file and the same jar file contains the image, URL.getFile() does the trick. I have tried it myself and it works like charm.

Comment: It will work in a few cases and fail in many other cases.  It is not reliable.  Plus, the question mentions opening the applet in a web site, so looking for files on the client computer may work when testing but is certainly going to fail when deployed.